# List Post Attachments - Remove Image Thumbnails

Tags: attachments

I'm using the following code to display a list of the posts attachments within a sidebar:

```
<ul>            
<?php $args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'post_parent' => $post->ID
);
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
        echo '<p>This article has the following attachments:</p>';
        foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        echo '<li class="document">';
        the_attachment_link($attachment->ID, false);
        echo '</li>';}
        } else { 
        echo '<li class="nodocument">No documents attached to this article.</li>';
} ?>
</ul>
```

Most posts contain PDF's, Zip files and JPG/PNG files. The code above does list the attachments, however, when the attachment is an image it displays a thumbnail rather than just a link to the image.

Can anyone advise how I can go about making sure each attachment is listed as a link?

Thanks,
Darren

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `the_attachment_link` use the following:

```
echo wp_get_attachment_link($attachment->ID, 'full', false, false, true);
```

`wp_get_attachment_link` is what's being called internally by `the_attachment_link`, the last parameter set to true makes it output a text link instead of an image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using your suggested code causes the title for each link to be "1" - very odd! However, I changed it to the following: `echo wp_get_attachment_link($attachment->ID, false, false, false, false);` now it returns the title of each attachment. Thanks very much for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Ah didn't actually test the code so that could be true ;) Glad you got it working!

Comment: one false should be enough :-) `echo wp_get_attachment_link($attachment->ID,false);`