# Adding thumbnails for non-image attachments

Tags: custom-field, images, customization, attachments, attachment-fields-to-edit

I'm working on a site that provides Photoshop resources. I would like to create a page offering brushes for download that displays a thumbnail image and a link to a .zip file for each brush set. I was thinking that I could attach the .zip files for all the brush sets to the page and then display the thumbnails. I was wondering if there might be a way to link a thumbnail image to the attachment and then display all of the thumbnails. My initial thought was to add a custom field for attachments that allowed you to upload a thumbnail. Then, use something like this, but modified to output the thumbnail with a link to the attachment itself [ [List Post Attachments - Remove Image Thumbnails](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29694/list-post-attachments-remove-image-thumbnails) ] to display all of the previews. Is there an existing plugin that allows you to upload thumbnails as a custom field to attachments, or can you tell me how to do so myself? (Or, if there's a better way to do this, I am all ears!) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would create a custom post type called brush, and use the featured image facility to provide a representative thumbnail. You could then create an archive-brush.php template to show them all.

Comment: I was unaware of custom post types, thanks for that! So what I would end up doing is uploading the .zip file as an attachment to a post in the brush type as well as a thumbnail, which I would set to featured image. In the archive-brush.php template, I can alter the loop to display the featured image and use something like this [ http://johnford.is/programmatically-pull-attachments-from-wordpress-posts/ ] except with a .zip mime-type and pull the .zip file's URL. Sound about right?

Comment: Sounds about right. This way you could also use a single-brush.php if you wanted, for extra detail/examples.

Comment: There still might be a necessity for such thumbnail. For example video attachments currently do not provide a field for the thumbnail, which is a drawback, to say at least.